# Como validar um e-mail em c

Tags: c

Eai galera. Preciso fazer uma verificação de e-mail com essas caracteristicas.

Email deve possuir: 3 caracteresou mais; um sinal de arroba (@); outros 3 caracteres ou mais; seguidos de um sinal de ponto final (.); e mais um conjunto de pelo menos 2 caracteres.

O que eu fiz foi isso, mas ele esta pulando algumas condições.

```
main(){

    int x;
    char email[50]={"Teste@hotmail.com"};
    int arroba,ponto,passa,maior,c_P,c_S,i;
    int tam=strlen(email);
    char teste='.';
     for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
       if(email[i] > 3){   
         maior=1;   
       }if(email[i] == '@'){
        arroba=1;

       }if(arroba == 1 &&  email[i] >= 3){
        c_P=1;
       }if(email[i]=='.'){
            ponto=1;
           }if(ponto=1 && email[i] >=2){
            c_S=1;
       }

    if(maior==1 && arroba == 1 && c_P==1 && c_S ==1){
        passa=1;
    }else{
        passa=0;
    }


    }  

    if(passa==1){
        printf("Valido");
    }else{
        printf("Invalido");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto é para alguma aula ou realmente precisa de um validador de e-mails eficiente?

Comment: sim é parte de uma trabalho que eu preciso entregar. Não posso usar ponteiros ou funções que façam isso no caso. Se você conhece uma forma melhor de fazer agradeço.

Comment: somente c ou pode c++?

Comment: preciso em C. Mas caso só saiba em c++ eu consigo tirar alguma idéia de como fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, seu programa tem alguns erros:

1. A formatação está bastante bagunçada
2. Não tem os #includes
3. Ao invés de `if(email[i] > 3)` deveria ser `if(i > 3)`
4. A linha `if(ponto=1 && email[i] >=2)` você esqueceu de colocar == (`ponto==1`)
5. Tem algumas variáveis criadas e não utilizadas
6. O código poderia ser bem mais simples, em todo caso, deve-se seguir sua lógica.

Neste link (https://ideone.com/KuQFF3) você poderá ver a versão sua sem erros de codificação, mas ainda assim não está detectando corretamente se o e-mail é valido.

Abaixo um código que fiz em C que resolve seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char email[50]={"abc@xyz.se"};
  int tam=strlen(email);
  int arroba = 0, ponto = 0, antesPonto = 0, depoisPonto = 0, i;

  for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    char c = email[i];
    if(c == '@') {
      if (arroba)
        break; // não pode ter uma segunda @
      arroba = 1;
      if (i < 3)
        break; // se @ vier antes de 3 caracteres, erro
    }
    else if (arroba) { // se já encontrou @
      if (ponto) { // se já encontrou . depois de @
        depoisPonto++;
      }
      else if(c == '.') {
        ponto = 1;
        if (antesPonto < 3) {
          break; // se . depois de @ vier antes de 3 caracteres, erro
        }
      }
      else {
        antesPonto++;
      }
    }
  } // for

  if (i == tam && depoisPonto > 1)
    printf("Valido");
  else
    printf("Invalido");
}
```

Veja funcionando em https://ideone.com/WdqZu1

Comment: Exato, mesmo assim ele não funciona muito bem. Se você tiver algum exemplo de código que eu possa olhar por que a lógica eu entendo, só que talvez tem maneira melhores de resolver isso.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com uma solução. Se estiver de acordo, por favor positive a resposta e dê como aceite.

Comment: if (arroba)
        break; no caso se o arroba é zero ele para?

Comment: 0 = FALSE, Not 0 = TRUE. `if (arroba)` é o mesmo que `if (arroba != 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal usar a função `sscanf()` da biblioteca padrão `stdio.h` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int validar_email( const char * email )
{
    char usuario[256], site[256], dominio[256];

    if( sscanf( email, "%[^@ \t\n]@%[^. \t\n].%3[^ \t\n]", usuario, site, dominio ) != 3 )
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if( !validar_email(argv[1]) )
    {
        printf("Invalido!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```